# How to combine CSS Linear gradient with images?

Tags: css, css-gradients

I have on the left a css Gradient, and on the left a slider with images.
How can i combine the two, so that the images on the right take the shape like on the images below ?

[image]

**UPDATE**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row shape-background">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.shape-background {
text-align: center;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%);
```

the problem is that when i add another backgroud image on the righr side of the same div, the linear gradient does not work.

Should i make my slider with `img` tag, or can i achieve this use case with background images ? 
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%);
    }

Comment: Please include your code... HTML, CSS, and ideally a snippet, thanks

Comment: I juste want the image slider on the right to have this shape, i have no code to show, i'm just trying to do this.

Comment: linear gradient is also a background-image. You need to keep both and set the gradient first: `background: linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, white 25%), url(myotherimageunderneathgradient.jpg) ; }`

Comment: does not works for me, the linear gradient apear but not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo from my comment:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(125deg, #e20613 25%, transparent 25%), url(http://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=my_image);
  border:solid;
}
html {
display:flex;
height:100%;
background:white;
}
```

but this doesn't make a slider.

[example of a css slider with image in the HTML](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rGOxeg)

Comment: OMG, finally the problem is that i use white unstead of transparent ! thx for your help.